# JavaFX - How to save user settings/configurations?

Tags: java, configuration, javafx, save

I have written a javafx program, where the user can open a text file, the text file gets stored in a dynamic tableview and the user can add rows/columns, delete rows/columns, convert columns, move columns, change cell value...etc.
How can I save all the user settings/configurations, so that for the next time the user has only to choose the source text-file and the configurations-file and it will be converted automatically..

I don't even know how/where to start..

I have searched for answers, but didn't found anything helpful...

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please specify exactly what part of this you are having trouble with. Clarify what you mean by "next file": do you want some configuration (what, exactly?) to persist to the next time the user starts the application, or just over the current application instance?

Comment: i updated the question.

Comment: You changed the text slightly but you didn't actually address any of the issues. Here is an answer that is as precise as your question: Put the information you want to persist into an appropriate data structure. When the user exits the program, save the data to a file. On startup, read the data in from the file and place it into the data structure you use, and then reference it in your application as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me that you'd like to persist user's preference on local computer.

If so, I'd recommand using [`java.util.prefs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can save the document settings in a XML and can on Click load the XML file with the properties in it. For the XML creating/reading you can use the [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) Library.